# Array not setting proper table name value in foreach even after unset

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have menu table where I am storing all the menus and want to display all on sidebar in one go under their parent menus. For that purpose I am organizing an array which I can use in view file.

Data I am getting from database is in this format

```
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [parent_menu_id] => 1
                    [tbl_name] => jobs
                    [menu_name] => Create Jobs
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [parent_menu_id] => 1
                    [tbl_name] => jobs
                    [menu_name] => Show Jobs
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [parent_menu_id] => 4
                    [tbl_name] => customers
                    [menu_name] => Create Customers
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [parent_menu_id] => 4
                    [tbl_name] => Customers
                    [menu_name] => Show Customers 
                )

        )
```

The format I am trying to achieve is this.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tbl_name] => jobs
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Create Jobs
                        [route] => jobs.create
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Show Jobs
                        [route] => jobs.assigned_jobs
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Show All Jobs
                        [route] => jobs.index
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [tbl_name] => customers
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Create Customers
                        [route] => customers.create
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Show Customers
                        [route] => customers.show
                    )

            )

    )
```

The only problem I am facing is it is repeating table name `[tbl_name] => jobs` even I have unset this in  loop you can see in my code.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tbl_name] => jobs
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Create Jobs
                        [route] => jobs.create
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Show Jobs
                        [route] => jobs.assigned_jobs
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Show All Jobs
                        [route] => jobs.index
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [tbl_name] => jobs
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [tbl_name] => jobs
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [tbl_name] => customers
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Create Customers
                        [route] => customers.create
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [menu_name] => Show Customers
                        [route] => customers.show
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [tbl_name] => Customers
            )
    )
```

Code

```
    $rec = menu::all();
$rec = $rec->toArray();

$results = [];
$results1 = [];


foreach ($rec as $key => $value) 
{

    $results['tbl_name'] = $value['tbl_name'];

    foreach ($rec as $kk => $vv)
    {
        if($vv['parent_menu_id'] == $value['id'])
        {
            $results[] = ['menu_name' => $vv['menu_name'], 'route' => $vv['route']];
            unset($rec[$kk]);
        }            
    }
        array_values($rec);            
        $results1[] = $results;
        $results = [];            
}
```

Comment: Your input data doesn't have a `route` field in the arrays, not sure how you expect to get that in the output?

Comment: Is `parent_menu_id` => `tbl_name` a `1:1` relationship?

Comment: Hi Nick Thanks alot for your attention, I have fixed it last night. I am answering my question below

Answer (score 0):

I fix it last night

```
public function sidebar_menu()
{

$rec = menu::all();
$rec = $rec->toArray();

$res1 = [];
$res2 = [];


foreach ($rec as $key => $value) 
{
    foreach ($rec as $kk => $vv)
    {
        if($vv['parent_menu_id'] == $value['id'])
        {
            $res1['tbl_name'] = $value['tbl_name'];
            $res1[] = ['menu_name' => $vv['menu_name'], 'route' => $vv['route']];
        }            
    }
    
    if(!empty($res1))
    {
        $res2[] = $res1;
        $res1 = [];        
      }
   }
   return $res2;
  }
```